# How to delay the operation until two datasets are all loaded in angular.js

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular.js to load two parts of data from two web services, and I need to match two dataset when they are all ready.

two parts of data in the angular.js are described as

```
$scope.myorders = [];
$scope.catalogs = [];
$http({
          url: baseURL + "data",
      }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
         $scope.myorders = data;
      })

// match two datasets
_.each($scope.myorders, function( order){
   _.each($scope.catalogs, function( catalog){

  })
})
```

However, sometimes the match operations are not consistent that only one dataset is loaded while the other is not loaded.

How can I sync the two datasets to make sure the match operation is executed after the two datasets are all loaded well

update:
I tried in this way

```
   var deferred1 = $q.defer();
   var deferred2 = $q.defer();

$http({
          url: baseURL + "data",
      }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
         $scope.myorders = data;
          console.log("deferred1.resolve");
          deferred1.resolve();
      })

$http({
          url: baseURL + "data2",
      }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
         $scope.catalogs = data;
         console.log("deferred2.resolve");
         deferred2.resolve();
      })

   $q.all([
            deferred1, 
            deferred2
        ])
        .then(function(values) {        
          console.log("all resolved");
          return values;
        });
```

I tried in this way, but guess it is not right, since the output sequence is not what I expect

```
"all resolved"
"deferred2.resolve"
"deferred1.resolv"
```

how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use angular [$q.all](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) to resolve data when 2 http calls are ready

example here in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ThomasBurleson/QqKuk/)

for each call you should create defered object push it into array then use

```
$q.all(deferesArray).then(
      function(resp){
         // all requests are resolver , resp is array with resolved datas
        }
  )
```

in your code you should do like this

```
   var deferred1 = $q.defer(); var deferred2 = $q.defer();

   $http({
              url: baseURL + "data",
          }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
             $scope.myorders = data;
              console.log("deferred1.resolve");
              deferred1.resolve(data);
          })

    $http({
              url: baseURL + "data2",
          }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
             $scope.catalogs = data;
             console.log("deferred2.resolve");
             deferred2.resolve(data);
          })

    $q.all([ deferred1, deferred2 ]) .then(function(values) {
    // your resolved values in this inside in this values variable 
    //
    console.log("RESOLVED WITH VALUES",values); 
   // and you should run your logical functions here
   // remember your values inside values array variable 
    // match two datasets
    _.each(values[0], function( order){
     _.each(values[1], function( catalog){

  })
 });
```

Comment: I have tried $q.all, as in the update, but still wrong.

Comment: i have updaed the example

Comment: Hi, Narek, my previous update is almost the same with your change, I have tried the deferred2.resolve(data); the all function always executes firstly before the other two deferred operations executes

Comment: is it possible to bring it in fiddle ?

Comment: Hi, Narek,  $q.all([ deferred1.promise, deferred2.promise ]) can make it work ultimately

Answer (score 1):

To get the [promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) from a deferred you have to call `deferred1.promise` on it. e.g. `$q.all([deferred1.promise, deferred2.promise]);`

But since `$http` already returns a promise, you can do the following:

```
var urls = ["example.com/foo", "example.com/bar"];
var results = [];
var promises = urls.map(function(url){
    return $http({
        method: "GET",
        url: url
    })
    .then(function(res){ //we probably also want to get each result
        results.push(res);
    });
});

$q.all(promises).then( function(lastvalue) {
    console.log(results);
}, function(err) {
    console.error(err);
});
```